# Strange RDP connection behaviour

Tags: networking, macos, remote-desktop, azure, vps

I have a strange problem with doing RDP to Azure Windows11 VM with my MacBook(pro).

I cannot do RDP when I am connected to home network. I am receiving below error:

> "Your session ended because of an error. If this keeps happening,
> contact your network administrator for assistance.
>
> Error code: 0x4

If I connect to my phone's hotspot then I can do RDP.
I have a second Mac (air). It can do RDP from both of the networks; home and hotspot.

Side notes:
MacBook Pro has M1 and company computer. It has Jamf.
MacBook air is 2017 model and personal one.

Summary:

| Environment | Network | RDP status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MacBookP | Home | Fails |
| MacBookP | Mobile | Success |
| MacBookA | Home | Success |
| MacBookA | Mobile | Success |

Comment: Try to : (1) Disable the firewall on MacBookP, (2)Does ping to the RDP target work? (3) Verify RDP version, (4) In RDP *Preferences > General* uncheck "Use system proxy configurations" and "Use hardware acceleration when possible".

Comment: 1. Since it is my company's computer, I cannot disable the firewall.
2. telnet works to ip and port for vm
3. will check
4. already tried. no luck:(